# Does the Ctype methods included in Iostream by default works in the settled locale in a program?

Tags: c++

I'm working with a class that only accepts certain characters for it's attributes, and I'm doing the cleansing in my setters, but anyway, that's not my question.

Would Ctype methods from C++ like "ispunct" will accept the punctuation chars from the locale the program is settled in?

```
//Let's say...
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Spanish_Mexico");

//Like, would this be a true statement?
ispunct('¿');
```

To be clear, I'm not using that comparison in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard C/C++ locale considers punctuation characters all graphic characters (as in isgraph) that are not alphanumeric (as in isalnum). So, yes it returns true.

Font:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/ispunct/